# How to pass a value of a parent component and a child component, vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

I have the following template of a parent component:

```
<template>
    <v-card class="pa-3 teal darken-3" flat height="100%">
        <ReportesViales v-bind:visualizar="sheet"></ReportesViales>
        <l-map class="map"  :zoom="zoom" :center="center" :options="{ zoomControl: false }">
            <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
            <l-marker :lat-lng="marker">
                <l-popup></l-popup>
            </l-marker>
            <l-control position="bottomleft" >
                <v-btn flat icon color="indigo" @click="ubicacion">
                    <v-icon>my_location</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                 <v-btn flat icon color="indigo" @click="sheet = true">
                    <v-icon>add_alert</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </l-control>
        </l-map>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

and I have a child component called 'ReportsViales'.

To which I send as parameter the variable 'sheet' that basically can be true or false, boolean type.

In the child component I receive it in the following way:

```
<template>
    <v-bottom-sheet v-model="visualizar">
        <v-list>
            <v-subheader>Opciones</v-subheader>
            <v-list-tile
            v-for="tile in tiles"
            :key="tile.title"
            @click="visualizar = false"
            >
            <v-list-tile-avatar>
                <v-icon :color="tile.color">{{tile.icon}}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-avatar>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ tile.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </v-bottom-sheet>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    props:['visualizar'],
    data(){
        return {
            tiles: [
                { icon: 'notification_important', title: 'Solicitar apoyo', color: '#00695C', tipo: 1 },
                { icon: 'warning', title: 'Reportar alerta', color: '#01579B', tipo: 2 },
                { icon: 'commute', title: 'Transito pesado', color: '#1B5E20', tipo: 3  },
                { icon: 'directions_car', title: 'Transito fluido', color: '#3E2723', tipo: 4 },
                { icon: 'departure_board', title: 'Bloqueado totalmente', color: '#FF3D00', tipo: 5 }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and it actually works for me once, but when I want to continue working with this component, the following error appears, and the child component no longer works:

Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders

Comment: Define a local data property visualizar. That way you get the default value from props and can the modify it’s value. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you are trying to mutate a variable that was passed in to the child component as a property.
That means data "ownership" lies with the parent and the parent should be the only one mutating it.

It now depends on what you're trying to achieve, do you specifically want any changes in `visualizar` to also propagate to the parent component, or does the parent just provide the default/starting value, and any changes in the child will only be transient and not concern the parent?

To keep a property value in sync you can use the `.sync` modifier (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

Just pass in the property as `visualizar.sync="sheet"` and within the child emit an update event instead of changing `visualizar` directly:

```
// replace this:
// @click="visualizar = false"
// with
@click="$emit('update:visualizar', false)"
```

Vue takes care of the rest and keeps them in sync.

If the parent doesn't care about any changes to `visualizar` just use a local `data` variable instead:

```
//in child:
data() {
  return {
    ...
    localVisualizar: this.visualizar,
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually if the father cares, do what you said but it did not work, maybe I added it incorrectly, if you could describe it according to the code I have, very grateful for your time.

Comment: @JG_GJ provide a https://codesandbox.io/ with your code that's not working and we might be able to help.